# How to transfer data to another sheet via hyperlink in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, data-transfer

In excel, I want to turn the dates mentioned below to hyperlinks and with that I want to transfer the values in the next cells in the same row to another sheet. I saw that it can be done by a button but I want to do it with a hyper link.

[image]

Comment: Not doable with a hyperlink, unless you want the hyperlink to trigger VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by implementing a listener to the sheet that the hyperlinks are in. However, it was inefficient thus I added buttons instead programatically.